# Как двухмерный python массив преобразовать в HTML таблицу?

Tags: python, html, массивы, коллекции, table

Надеюсь сегодня у вас отличное настроение, но перейдем к сути вопроса.

Есть list:

```
relations_table = [[0 for i in range(0, len(sounds))] for j in range(0, len(sounds))]
for i in relations:
    relations_table[i.left_sound_id-1][i.right_sound_id-1] = i.weight
```

Выглядит примерно так:

```
[[25, 98, 40, 17, 66, 65, 41, 11, 70, 58], [89, 93, 35, 89, ...
```

Как заполнить эти данные в html таблицу, где индекс обозначает ряд и столбец клетки со значением?

Если можно пример кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

```
relations_table = [[25, 98, 40, 17, 66, 65, 41, 11, 70, 58], [89, 93, 35, 89, 40, 17, 66, 65, 41, 99]]

html = '<table>'
for row in relations_table:
    html += '<tr>'
    for value in row:
        html += '<td>{}</td>'.format(value)
    html += '</tr>'
html += '</table>'

print(html)
```

---

Другой вариант, более удобный для сложных данных – [шаблонизатор jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/):

```
# pip install jinja2
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template('''
<table cellspacing="2" border="1" cellpadding="5">
    {% for row in relations_table %}
    <tr>
        {% for value in row %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}    
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
''')

html = template.render(relations_table=relations_table)
print(html)
```

Вот так будет выглядеть таблица в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно и более сложные штуки создавать. [Пример генерации html](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/web_servers/get_upload_and_image_process/main.py#L84) страницы через jinja2

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

html = pd.DataFrame(relations_table).to_html(header=None, index=False, border=2)

with open('d:/temp/a.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пандас просто супер модуль для работы с табличками :)

Comment: @gil9red, с этим трудно не согласиться :)

Answer (score 0):

[json2html](https://pypi.org/project/json2html/) преобразует JSON в табличное представление

```
html = json2html.json2html.convert(json=relations_table, escape=False, table_attributes='id=\"info-table\"')
```